# CSS dvw and dvh do not ineract well with padding? padding-bottom not shown even if it is considered?

Tags: css

I recently came across dvh while doing a side project and wanted a filler div to push footer on the bottom of the screen when not enough content in page, a topic that feels too painful whenever I'm near it even though it seems simple.

I do use (flexbox and) complimentary height and top-bottom padding to add up to 100dvh and it works fine when the content is not enough to fill the view port. When the content is more than enough (scroll appears), going all the way to the bottom the padding-bottom doesn't show, padding-top shows. I also checked with Chrome's inspect and confirmed that there is actually amount calculated for the padding-bottom and padding-top.

Is this expected behavior? I tried reading the documentation and some articles commenting on dynamic view port units, but I can't say I have deep knowledge on CSS to reason about it.

Run the snippet and click/tap on the output window to fill and empty the content to see the difference.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const elem = document.getElementById("aid");
  if( elem.innerHTML == "" ) {
    elem.innerHTML = "Some long content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec molestie metus ac nunc hendrerit suscipit. Aenean convallis accumsan gravida. Ut lobortis turpis ut orci efficitur, at eleifend arcu ultricies. Ut tempus eget neque efficitur auctor. Donec sagittis, augue et rhoncus vulputate, purus sem malesuada elit, id rhoncus dolor nulla placerat velit. Suspendisse purus quam, consequat quis turpis ut, tempor elementum nulla. Pellentesque nibh risus, aliquet sit amet felis placerat, lobortis vehicula nisl. Sed convallis turpis sodales ligula egestas, a ultrices libero ultrices. Sed in ipsum urna. Suspendisse aliquet mollis enim. Aliquam mollis est vitae dignissim finibus. Sed nulla tortor, ultricies eget aliquet a, consectetur at enim. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam sodales ligula eget lacus maximus, ut suscipit augue tristique. Phasellus ac tortor dolor. Etiam ornare tempor semper. Fusce rutrum arcu a est iaculis varius. Curabitur libero augue, bibendum non leo sit amet, malesuada blandsse purus quam, consequat quis turpis ut, tempor elementum nulla. Pellentesque nibh risus, aliquet sit amet felis placerat, lobortis vehicula nisl. Sed convallis turpis sbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam sodales ligula eget lacus maximus, ut suscipit augue tristique. Phasellus ac tortor dolor. Etiam ornare tempor semper. Fusce rutrum arcu a est iaculis varius. Curabitur libero augue, bibendum non leo sit amet, malesuada blandsse purus quam, consequat quis turpis ut, tempor elementum nulla. Pellentesque nibh risus, aliquet sit amet felis placerat, lobortis vehicula nisl. Sed convallis turpis sodales ligula egestas, a ultrices libero ultrices. Sed in ipsum urna. Suspendisse aliquet mollis enim. Aliquam mollis est vitae dignissim finibus. Sed nulla tortor, ultricies eget aliquet a, consectetur at enim. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam sodales ligula eget lacus maximus, ut suscipit augue tristique. Phasellus ac tortor dolor. Etiam ornare tempor semper. Fusce rutrum arcu a est iaculis varius. Curabitur libero augue, bibendum non leo sit amet, malesuada blandit nunc. Maecenas pulvinar ligula et arcu feugiat egestas. Nunc quis viverra ante. Donec purus augue, iaculis a dui ut, ullamcorper viverra massa. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam elementum ipsum nunc, quis dictum massa convallis quis. Morbi neque risus, mattis sodales lobortis eu, iaculis a sapien. Suspendisse aliquet mollis enim. Aliquam mollis est vitae dignissim finibus. Sed nulla tortor, ultricies eget aliquet a, consectetur at enim. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam sodales ligula eget lacus maximus, ut suscipit augue tristique. Phasellus ac tortor dolor. Etiam ornare tempor semper. Fusce rutrum arcu a est iaculis varius. Curabitur libero augue, bibendum non leo sit amet, malesuada blandit nunc. Maecenas pulvinar ligula et arcu feugiat egestas. Nunc quis viverra ante. Donec purus augue, iaculis a dui ut, ullamcorper viverra massa. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam elementum ipsum nunc, quis dictum massa convallis quis. Morbi neque risus, mattis sodales lobortis eu, iaculis a sapien.";
  }
  else {
    elem.innerHTML = "";
  }
}, true);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 96dvh;
  /* here */ padding: 2dvh 0;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fill {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.header, .footer {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div id=aid></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

Similar for dvw, less use cases.

Comment: I suspect this is due to the `height` being restricted to "device height" and `overflow` kicking in. If you change `height` to `min-height` then overflow doesn't occur and the padding shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Paulie_D say, you can avoid this overflow issue by changing `height` to `min-height`

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const elem = document.getElementById("aid");
  if( elem.innerHTML == "" ) {
    elem.innerHTML = "Some long content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec molestie metus ac nunc hendrerit suscipit. Aenean convallis accumsan gravida. Ut lobortis turpis ut orci efficitur, at eleifend arcu ultricies. Ut tempus eget neque efficitur auctor. Donec sagittis, augue et rhoncus vulputate, purus sem malesuada elit, id rhoncus dolor nulla placerat velit. Suspendisse purus quam, consequat quis turpis ut, tempor elementum nulla. Pellentesque nibh risus, aliquet sit amet felis placerat, lobortis vehicula nisl. Sed convallis turpis sodales ligula egestas, a ultrices libero ultrices. Sed in ipsum urna. Suspendisse aliquet mollis enim. Aliquam mollis est vitae dignissim finibus. Sed nulla tortor, ultricies eget aliquet a, consectetur at enim. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam sodales ligula eget lacus maximus, ut suscipit augue tristique. Phasellus ac tortor dolor. Etiam ornare tempor semper. Fusce rutrum arcu a est iaculis varius. Curabitur libero augue, bibendum non leo sit amet, malesuada blandsse purus quam, consequat quis turpis ut, tempor elementum nulla. Pellentesque nibh risus, aliquet sit amet felis placerat, lobortis vehicula nisl. Sed convallis turpis sbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam sodales ligula eget lacus maximus, ut suscipit augue tristique. Phasellus ac tortor dolor. Etiam ornare tempor semper. Fusce rutrum arcu a est iaculis varius. Curabitur libero augue, bibendum non leo sit amet, malesuada blandsse purus quam, consequat quis turpis ut, tempor elementum nulla. Pellentesque nibh risus, aliquet sit amet felis placerat, lobortis vehicula nisl. Sed convallis turpis sodales ligula egestas, a ultrices libero ultrices. Sed in ipsum urna. Suspendisse aliquet mollis enim. Aliquam mollis est vitae dignissim finibus. Sed nulla tortor, ultricies eget aliquet a, consectetur at enim. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam sodales ligula eget lacus maximus, ut suscipit augue tristique. Phasellus ac tortor dolor. Etiam ornare tempor semper. Fusce rutrum arcu a est iaculis varius. Curabitur libero augue, bibendum non leo sit amet, malesuada blandit nunc. Maecenas pulvinar ligula et arcu feugiat egestas. Nunc quis viverra ante. Donec purus augue, iaculis a dui ut, ullamcorper viverra massa. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam elementum ipsum nunc, quis dictum massa convallis quis. Morbi neque risus, mattis sodales lobortis eu, iaculis a sapien. Suspendisse aliquet mollis enim. Aliquam mollis est vitae dignissim finibus. Sed nulla tortor, ultricies eget aliquet a, consectetur at enim. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam sodales ligula eget lacus maximus, ut suscipit augue tristique. Phasellus ac tortor dolor. Etiam ornare tempor semper. Fusce rutrum arcu a est iaculis varius. Curabitur libero augue, bibendum non leo sit amet, malesuada blandit nunc. Maecenas pulvinar ligula et arcu feugiat egestas. Nunc quis viverra ante. Donec purus augue, iaculis a dui ut, ullamcorper viverra massa. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam elementum ipsum nunc, quis dictum massa convallis quis. Morbi neque risus, mattis sodales lobortis eu, iaculis a sapien.";
  }
  else {
    elem.innerHTML = "";
  }
}, true);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100dvh;
  padding: 2dvh 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fill {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.header, .footer {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div id=aid></div>
  <div class="fill"></div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the box-sizing as well in order to not need the complementary values.

Comment: Has this any potential unwanted behavior? I mean it is a limit that changes (min) and the actual height gets pushed or pulled according to it, to do the trick. (asking any, tagging @Paulie_D since you mentioned it initially)